# What does finished threads mean in jmeter headless mode?

Tags: jmeter

I am running a JMeter test in headless mode and here is part of my answer:

[image]

As you see, it always **Starts** by 50 threads, but then only a few portion of threads remain **Active** and more than half of them are **Finished**.

I have 2 questions:

1. I am not sure, but I guess "**Finished**" is the number of dead threads? Right?
2. How can I know, why it happens? Normally, I expect that **Finished** is always %0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/3-easy-ways-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-test-results/) answered me very well:

> **Active**: shows the number of active users who were performing requests
>   for this period
>
> **Started**: shows the total number of started threads
>   since the beginning of the tests
>
> **Finished**: shows the total number of
>   threads that already finished execution since the beginning of tests